# Loop in CellValueChanged event in DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a billing application. The problem is that I want to increase the speed of billing to be as fast and smooth as possible so am using a DataGridView for this purpose.

Is there any example program using datagrid for billing?

### Problem in my application

The problem is that when a product is selected and quantity is entered say 100 in stock sometimes 50 may be there in one batch, so I want to add 50 from other batch
and I want to show the new as new record.

User will enter 100 in quantity column I want to cancel it and want to change it to 50
here is the problem when trying to change it looping occurs in `CellValueChanged`.

Since value of grid is changing in `CellValueChanged` event it will be called again how can I solve this or please give me some sample program links

Comment: The best resource for the DataGridView is the FAQ http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc

Answer (score 2):

The normal way I accomplish this is with a private class member variable called

```
bool suspendEventCellValueChanged;
```

And in my handler, only proceed to make modifications if `suspendEventCellValueChanged == false`. If I proceed, I set `suspendEventCellValueChanged = true`, so that I don't get caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: [Its being enlightened here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794990/datagridview-c-sharp-edit-mode-value-formatting-after-edit/9796202#9796202) :)