# DataGridView C# Edit Mode Value Formatting After Edit

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, event-handling

I have a datagridview in a C# Winform project.  This datagridview is used to insert values into a database.  Each column matches up to a corresponding db column.

One of the columns is a DateTime column.  I want to 'validate' this date to ensure it is in the proper format.  Ideally, you would leave the cell and it would convert it to a date time format that I choose.

I have used a series of events to attempt creating this functionality but have been having problems.  The problem that I keep having is that when the event fires, the value has not been stored in the cell yet.  Therefore, when I do something like this for example:

```
private void Grid_Modify_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (Grid_Modify.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DateTime")
    {
        Grid_Modify[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = 
           Convert.ToDateTime(Grid_Modify[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value).ToString("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

Problem is, the value it is converting to a datetime is the original cell value -- not the new value I just entered.  I assume this is because the event is firing before the cell value is being updated.

Question is: What is the best way of formatting the date when I change its value?

The other events I have tried are: CellLeave, CellValueChanged, CellValidated, and CellEndEdit.

NOTE: CellValueChanged event was the only event that actually could get the new cell value, however, it gets caught in an infinite loop when I change the value within the eventhandler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest would be to go back to CellValueChanged event handler and use a global variable to avoid your infinite loop:

```
 private bool _inCellValueChanged = false;
```

Then, in CellValueChanged:

```
if (!_inCellValueChanged && Grid_Modify.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DateTime") 
{ 
    _inCellValueChanged = true;        
    Grid_Modify[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Grid_Modify[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value).ToString("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
    _inCellValueChanged = false; 
}
```

Comment: The related problem I had was that the TimeColumns defaulted to the current date when I entered a new time value, even though they are called "Time Columns", all that is visible is the Time portion of the DateTime, and all the user can edit is the Time portion. This was a pragmatic solution.